# Difference between the questions starting with Did/Had/Have

Tags: tense, questions

What's the difference between below questions? Are they the same?

1. Did you see the movie?
2. Have you seen the movie?
3. Had you seen the movie?

I have used question 1 and 2 in situations when I have to enquire if the subject has performed the action.

For example:
Have you completed your homework?
Have you done the laundry?
Did you send the mail?
Did you finish writing your essay?

Am I correct to use 1 and 2 this way?   Is there any difference between the two.

I am not sure when to I use question 3?
Can somebody give examples of questions using had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between these questions are differences of context. People would tend to use them in different circumstances. For example:

> Did you see the movie on Channel 2 last night?

This generally refers back to a completed action/event.

> Have you seen the movie that is showing at the Odeon?

This generally refers to a continuing action/event - or to a past action whose effects/implications continue into the present.

> Had you seen the movie, you would have been most impressed by the actors.

This is another way of saying: **If you had seen the movie, .........**

Your examples are all idiomatic.